# Surds question grade 10

Tags: radicals, square-numbers, radical-equations

I am a student and need help answering this question. I need a step by step solution.

Simplify:

$ \sqrt {18}$ - $ \sqrt {9}$

What I tried:

($ \sqrt {9}$ × $ \sqrt {2}$) - 9

= (3$ \sqrt {2}$ ) - 9

I don't know what to do next.

Thank you and help is appreciated.

Comment: You have to simplify

Comment: Why did you cancel the $\sqrt\ $ in the first passage?

Answer (score 2):

this is $$\sqrt{2\cdot 9}-\sqrt{9}=3\sqrt{2}-3$$

Comment: $=3(\sqrt{2}-1)$, sorry OCD

Answer (score 1):

Here is a mistake you've made:

Going from the first step to the second step, you should have put the square root: $$\sqrt{18}-\sqrt{9} \implies (\sqrt{9}\times \sqrt{2})-\color{red}{\sqrt{9}}$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thank you for helping me answer this question